# getting something outside a div

Tags: html, css

Well I'm not sure how to ask this with words so I will post an image:

[image]

So in the image, there is a main div, lets call it "red".

Inside "red" there is another `div` called: "green"

Inside "green" there is an `ul`, with some `li` elements, they are supposed to have an underline, but that underline must get out of the div, so the problem I have, is getting that line outside of "green", when in the code, it is inside.

I'm guessing there might be some kind of overflow setting or some technique to achieve this, maybe its much easier than I think, but I just can't figure it out.

The sum it up, I need to get something from within a div, and get it to show outside of it as well.

I tried to google it as much as I could but I couldn't find anything that worked for me, maybe because I'm not even sure how to ask.

Comment: Have you tried ´overflow: visible;´ and ´left: -50px´?

Comment: Post CSS for all elements in this example. I reckon it has to do with the way you position green div. Because normally it shouldn't be like that.

Comment: @looper well the thing is, the -50 would be dynamic, so i thought about using a very big value like -999, but i figured there might be a better way, also the border is on the li item, so if i apply the left:-50, it would also move the text.

Comment: @AlexKey normally its not like that, the thing is, i need it to be like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on situation. If it is fixed size elements and they are always same size no matter what you could do it:
Position `red div` as `relative`, then `green div` as `absolute` and `ul` again as absolute. That will allow you move elements. Relatively to red div.
If it is stretching elements depending on size of window, it is harder and `margin-left`, `margin-top` and `float:left` would do the trick, but you should be very careful with it as it is hard to make cross-browser.

Comment: so would you recommend using a manual line instead of a border? i dont really want to move the text out of the div, i just want the border to go all the way to the left.

Comment: @Xeinnex Well, the underline, should be aligned with text, so it should wrap text around as element, or as CSS be part of element. Thus  you anyway should move element outside of green box.

Comment: yeah so i guess making a new element for the line would be the best option, instead of using a border on the li, i want the text part of the li to render normally inside its box.

Comment: @Xeinnex Is it necessary to put `ul` into green div? You can just do similar `margin-left` for green div and text-indent for `li`. Or (again depending on situation) you may no need green div at all, but make background out of blocks within `li` elements.

Comment: ok the thing is, i already got that effect, the problem i have, is when it comes to resizing, the gap where the line is overflowing shrinks, so i need it to stay the same in the green box, just having it change in the red one.

Comment: As i said before standard CSS solutions would work in case if it is fixed structure, otherwise it will be hard to achieve. Also i cannot say more just because i have not enough information. What exactly effect should it be? What are surrounding elements? Maybe it can be easier generated on server side (if it is accessible of course)? etc. too many uncertain details.

Comment: lets say the green box has a set margin:0 auto; which centers it horizontally, then when i make the browser smaller, it resizes the green box to keep it in the center. The line should actually get its offset when it resizes but i guess im going to have to use some javascript to make it happen, hopefully i dont run into too many cross browser issues

Comment: I see now. Then Javascript would be a last chance there, but benefit is that you can make calculations every time window resizes and you can give underline span as big as needed. Then i would keep ul inside green box, but using JS find position of li, then its y-position + its height give us position where underline should be.

Comment: thanks a lot, i guess im comfortable enough with this results, however i dont particularly enjoy having to use javascript for this, i usually try to do as many stuff as i can with basic css, but well sometimes its just not possible to do everything with css

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve this with overflow. What you need to do is to let the `ul` inside green be set to `position: absolute` and the red box to `position: relative`.

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helmers/VxjeY/2/) for it (my first).

Comment: the only problem with it, is that i cant use a text-indent like that because the distance might change.

Answer (score 0):

see the demo as per your requirement :- 
[**DEMO**](http://tinkerbin.com/PhAWjURF)

**HTML**

```
<div class="red">
<div class="green">
  <ul>
    <li>loreum</li>
    <li>loreum</li>
        <li>loreum</li>
    <li>loreum</li>
  </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:red;  
}

    .green {
        float: right;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 30px 30px 0;
        width: 200px;
    background:green;
    }

    .green ul {
        left: 8px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .green ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
      text-align:right;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "overflow : hidden" (css) for green div

Comment: it seems like some people got the question backwards, its not that i want to remove the overflow, what i want to do is to create an overflow.

Comment: No, that would render the underline, even if it would overflow the `green` div correctly, invisible.